# Is Mr. X and us working on Monday?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, questions

I want to ask my friend if he and I along with Mr. X are working on Monday?
Can you guys tell me how can I ask this?

Do you think the below question are correct?

**Is Mr. X and us working on Monday?

Are Mr. X and we working on Monday?**

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in the first example. "Is" is a singular verb referring to one subject, but you have two subjects, "Mr.X" and "us", so the correct verb is "are."

Likewise, "us" in the first is the object form of the collective pronoun. We can't say "us are working." "We" is the subject form, i.e., "we are working."

Therefore, the second example is correct. **Are** Mr. X and **we** working on Monday?

Comment: Could you explain subjective and objective? Google search shows objective word has no feelings while Subjective has feelings. I dont know how to relate this to 'us' Vs 'we'

Comment: I misspoke when I said "subjective" and "objective." I meant "subject" and "object." I edited it accordingly.